# Is necessity to use full join for my current task for joining multiple table in mysql

Tags: mysql

My task is selecting some columns from multiple table. I think it might should use full join. But I am not sure. And mysql seems not support full join either. My tasks described below:

**Tables** in my task:

Table **projects**

`id |  pname |  status
21 |   pr1  |  1
22 |   pr2  | -1
23 |   pr3  |  1
24 |   pr4  |  1
...         ........
   |        |`


Table **apps**

`projectid |  appstype |  status
21        |    3      |  1
22        |    5      | -1
22        |    6      |  1
22        |    7      | -1
23        |    7      |  1
24        |    5      | -1
...         ........
          |           |`


Table **crinfo**

`projectid |  crname |  status
21        | crname1 |  1
22        | crname2 | -1
23        | crname2 | -1
22        | crname3 | -1
24        | crname3 |  1
...         ........
          |         |`


Table **sourcedim**

ForeignKey *appstype* reference from Table **apps**

`appstype |  sourcedesc
   3     |  desc3
   5     |  desc5
   7     |  desc7
...         ........
         |`

**Expected Results**

`pname | crname  |  sourcedesc
 pr1  | crname1 |  desc3
 pr3  |         |  desc7
 pr4  | crname3 |
...         ........`

Comment: Hopefully not, because MySQL does not support `full join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (fortunately) because MySQL does not support `full join`.  You can use `left join`.  If I understand the data and logic correctly:

```
select p.pname, c.crname, sd.sourcedesc
from projects p left join
     crinfo c
     on p.id = c.projectid and c.status = 1 left join
     apps a
     on p.id = a.projectid and a.status = 1 left join
     sourcedim sd
     on a.appstype = sd.appstype
where p.status = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I really confused about the sql logic. It works for me. Wonderful answer. Thanks.